# JQuery:show/hide textbox with checkbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have 6 checkbox and 6 textbox respectively as shown in the below script ,

http://jsfiddle.net/ramu_steve/H6dBW/1/

When ever i check a checkbox(radio button functionality) corresponding textbox is shown.. but when i move to check other checkbox,the textbox shown for previous checkbox is not been hidden until we uncheck the checkbox
...Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using checkboxes if you want radio button functionality?

Answer (score 1):

How about a simpler code?

Live example: http://jsbin.com/ewekit/1/edit

```html
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label for="r1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="r1" name="r1" /> First Hotel Visit
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="t1" name="t1" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="r2">
        <input type="checkbox" id="r2" name="r2" /> Repeat Hotel Visit
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="t2" name="t2" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="r3">
        <input type="checkbox" id="r3" name="r3" /> Fish Bowl
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="t3" name="t3" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="r4">
        <input type="checkbox" id="r4" name="r4" /> Large Party
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="t4" name="t4" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="r5">
        <input type="checkbox" id="r5" name="r5" /> Generic
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="t5" name="t5" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="r6">
        <input type="checkbox" id="r6" name="r6" /> Corp Marketing
      </label>
      <input type="text" id="t6" name="t6" />
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Javascript

```js
$(function() {

  // hide all text inputs
  hideAllTextInputs();

  // radio click
  $("ul input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {

    // current <li>
    var li = $(this).closest("li");

    // show it's text
    li.find("input[type='text']").show();

    // hide all again
    hideAllTextInputs();
  });

});

function hideAllTextInputs() {
  // hide all text inputs
  $("ul input[type='checkbox']")
    .not(":checked")
    .closest("li")
    .find("input[type='text']")
    .hide();
}
```

Comment: The code looks better but the checkbox is not having the radiobutton functionality

Comment: @Ram you need to specify what is what you want, in your question you mention *"the textbox shown for previous checkbox is not been hidden until we uncheck the checkbox"* and that's what it does. If you want a radio functionality, why not just use `radio` buttons instead? Let me know what are you really after in plain English so we can understand.

Comment: I think he already has his answer ... some people understood what he wants

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you wrote a separate event for each textbox. This code can be completely implemented using just a single event..

```
$(function() {
    // Hide all Textboxes on DOM ready
    $('.typ').hide();

    //Create the click event for check box
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
        // Hide All Text Boxes
        $('.typ').hide();
        var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
        if(isChecked){  
            // Uncheck ALl the checkboxes
            $('.lettertyp').attr('checked', false);
            // Check curret checkbox
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
            // Find the Sibling of the TextBox and SHow it
            $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type=text]').show();
        }         
        else{
        }   
    });
});​
```

Check the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/fNtzT/) here

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is when a box is clicked, hide all textboxes, and then show the textbox for the button that was clicked. **[Check out this updated jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/H6dBW/3/)** What I have done is add `id='table'` to your table element and then under your code for the class of `lettertyp` added this code:

```
$('#table input[type="text"]').hide();
```

This selects all textboxes and hides them all. Then your code continues after this and shows the box that was selected.

Comment: he doesn't want that - he wants every txt box with a checked check box to be visible - there could be multiple

Comment: @ScottSelby - I don't think so because he said he wants radio button functionality. And looking at his jsFiddle, after you select another checkbox the old one gets turned off.

Comment: @Aust for just hiding, you do not need to loop through each element, you can easily do: `$('#table input[type="text"]').hide();`

Comment: who knows, I'm going to sleep

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe this is what you're trying to do with all that code, not really sure as I only got halfway through it ?

```
$(function() {
    $('[id^="typ"]').hide();
    $(".lettertyp").on('change', function() {
        $(".lettertyp").not(this).prop('checked', false);
        $('[id^="typ"]').hide();
        $("#"+this.id.replace('letter', '')).toggle(this.checked);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/H6dBW/4/)

Comment: @ScottSelby - I just deleted it and started over, got a headache from all those document.ready, but I think this does what's asked for, but I'm not sure ?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/H6dBW/11/

```
//Select Promo Letter Type 
$(document).ready(function(){
    //CheckBoxes behaviour
    $(".lettertyp").click(function(){
        $(".lettertyp").attr('checked',false);
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
    });

    //Hide all textboxes   
    $('.typ').hide();

    //Hide FisrtHotelVist
    $('#lettertyp1').click(function(){
        $('.typ').hide();
        $('#typ1').show();
    }); 
    // Hide Repeat HotelVisit
    $('#lettertyp2').click(function(){
        $('.typ').hide();
        $('#typ2').show();
    }); 
    //Hide Fish bowl
    $('#lettertyp3').click(function(){
        $('.typ').hide();
        $('#typ3').show();
    }); 
    //Hide LargeParty
    $('#lettertyp4').click(function(){
        $('.typ').hide();
        $('#typ4').show();
    }); 
    //Hide Generic 
    $('#lettertyp5').click(function(){
        $('.typ').hide();
        $('#typ5').show();
    }); 
    //hide corpMarketing
    $('#lettertyp6').click(function(){
        $('.typ').hide();
        $('#typ6').show();
    }); 
});
```

ok balexandre, then http://jsfiddle.net/H6dBW/18/

```
//Select Promo Letter Type 
$(document).ready(function(){
    //Hide all textboxes   
    $('.typ').hide();

    //CheckBoxes behaviour
    $(".lettertyp").click(function(){
        $(".lettertyp").attr('checked',false);
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
        $('.typ').hide();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id.substr(id.length - 1);
        $('#typ' + id).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: then again .. you're repeating yourself ... try to code smarter :)

Comment: great, but... it does not represent the behavior of the question: *the textbox shown for previous checkbox is not been hidden until we uncheck the checkbox* - http://jsbin.com/ewekit/1/edit ;)

Comment: yeah ... that's the problem ... so I fixed it ... you don't have to uncheck the box to hide the textbox, just click on another one ... that's the way I understood it